# newbie question about nhibernate mapping and guid

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, mapping, int, guid

My database have column `MyId` which is `INT` PK.
In mapping file I have line

```
Id(x => x.Id, "MyId").GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
```

I know this are two different types, guid and int but my question is:
Is it possible to to keep MyId as INT in my database and dynamicly convert this record to GUID on server level. For example if I want to retreive fetch my request and convert int as guid.
Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert a 4 byte signed integer into a 16 byte binary value.

You can do it the other ways and generate an int from a GUID using [CHECKSUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx) but you will get collisions ([birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)) eventually

Not quite sure why you want to change your key this way. Do you have GUID as the clustered PK?